# Thingsboard cannot connect to external DB postgresql google cloud

Tags: postgresql, gcloud, thingsboard

I am trying to get thingsboard running with an external database in order to separate my app server from my db server.

Right now thingsboard is running on a vm instance on google cloud, it is connected to a postgresql database running on the same server.

I created a postgresql fully managed db in google cloud, I can access it from pgadmin4 from my local machine and I can connect to it with PSQL from my application server.

The problem is that when I try to connect thingsboard to the new db the service will not start, The lines I change in "thingsboard.yml" file are `url: "${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://MYPUBLICDBIP:5432/thingsboard}"
password: "${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:MYDBPASSWORDFORUSERpostgres}"`

Am I missing something? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue sorted out, the problem was related to the lenght/complexity of the password, I was using special characters and a lenght of 32.
Changed to a 22 character alphanumeric password and it worked correctly. I do not know if it was the lenght or the precence of special characters.